# MvcMailer: Can't complete NUnit tests on Razor Views which use Url.Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nunit, razor, moq, mvcmailer

Here's my problem - I am using [MvcMailer](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/) to create nicely formatted emails using Razor syntax, and it's a great tool to use for that!

The issue I'm running into is this - here's some syntax from my View for one of the emails i send:

```
<p>Click here to return to <a href="@Url.Abs(Url.Action("Details", "Home", new{ Id=ViewBag.IdeaId}))">@ViewBag.IdeaName</a></p>
```

Whenever I try to run my unit tests, I get the following error message:

> Can we send out email notifications for new comments?: System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: httpContext

Stacktrace - shortened for brevity, relevant sections only:

> at System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection.GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
>   at Mvc.Mailer.MailerBase.CreateControllerContext()
>   at Mvc.Mailer.MailerBase.ViewExists(String viewName, String masterName)
>   at Castle.Proxies.Invocations.MailerBase_ViewExists.InvokeMethodOnTarget()
>   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()

The issue is that my HttpContext is null - is there a straightforward way to unit test this MvcMailer method without having to mock everything from the controller context all the way down the route results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take a look at the section titled **Unit Test Your Mailers** at the [MvcMailer wiki](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide) All you need to do is, just mock out the PopulateBody method and then it will bypass the view rendering as a part of the testing. It should look something like the following:

```
_userMailerMock.Setup(mailer => mailer.PopulateBody(It.IsAny<MailMessage>(), "Welcome", null));
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

This syntax worked for me:

```
var userMailerMock = new Mock<UserMailer> {CallBase = true};
userMailerMock.Setup(mailer => mailer.PopulateBody(It.IsAny<MailMessage>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<Dictionary<string, string>>()));
```

You might want to mock the other overload as well (if the above doesn't help or just to be sure):

```
userMailerMock.Setup(mailer => mailer.PopulateBody(It.IsAny<MailMessage>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<Dictionary<string,string>>()));
```