# MvcMailer unit test with Rhino Mock, how to?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, nunit, rhino-mocks, mvcmailer

In a new project we use MvcMailer, it's great and I would like to know how I can test it using Rhino and NUnit? There's an other [post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575964/mvcmailer-cant-complete-nunit-tests-on-razor-views-which-use-url-action) and a [good Wiki page](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide) but it's not what I'm looking for. For my controllers I usualy test them with [MvcContrib's Testhelper](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TestHelper&referringTitle=Documentation)

- I try first to mock the mailer class but if I do this I can't verify my ViewBag data, I'm having problem with the PopulateBody method and I have to build my own IMailerBase interface
- I try after this to test the mailer as I do with controller using MvcContrib but it only accept Controller object in the InitializeController() so it did'nt work.
- There's also a IsTestModeEnabled property in the [MailerBase.cs class](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/blob/master/Mvc.Mailer/MailerBase.cs) but when I test against it I get an error on empty URI.

Don't know what is the best way to do this and I'm looking for help, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the code how I did it :

```
// arrange
    var passwordMailer = MockRepository.GeneratePartialMock<PasswordMailer>();
    passwordMailer.Stub(mailer => mailer.PopulateBody(Arg<MailMessage>.Is.Anything, Arg.Is("ForgotPassword"), Arg<string>.Is.Null, Arg<Dictionary<string, string>>.Is.Null));

    // act
    var mailMessage = passwordMailer.ForgotPassword("test@example.com", "4454-8838-73773");

    // assert
    Assert.AreEqual(string.Format(Login.mailBody, "4454-8838-73773"), passwordMailer.ViewBag.Body);
    Assert.AreEqual(Login.mailSubject, mailMessage.Subject);
    Assert.AreEqual("test@example.com", mailMessage.To.First().ToString());
```

As you can see it, you can achieve it using partialMock functionnality from Rhino.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, can you tell me how GeneratePartialMock id different from a DynamicMock?

Comment: A normal mock object will throw an exception when a method, which has no explicit expectation defined, is called on the mock instance. A dynamic mock, instead of throwing an exception, will return null or 0 for any unexpected method calls. A partial mock, like a dynamic mock, will not throw an exception if a method is called when there is no expectation defined for the method; but, instead of returning 0 or null, a partial mock will call the actual implementation method (i.e., not the mock) on the object and return that value. This lets you selectively mock specific methods on an object.

Comment: that's why I mock only PopulateBody method and let the default implementation do the rest