# MvcMailer unit tests: System.ArgumentNullException httpContext cannot be null

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-3, moq, mvcmailer

I cannot successfully run unit tests for MvcMailer using the visual studio test suite and Moq. 
I have copied the example from the wiki word for word but get the following exception every time:

```
Test method MvcMailerTest.Tests.MailerTest.TestMethod1 threw exception: 
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: httpContext
```

Code is as follows: (Using the VS unit test framework - exact same error when using nUnit as in the example)

```
        //Arrange: Moq out the PopulateBody method
        var _userMailerMock = new Mock<UserMailer>();
        _userMailerMock.Setup(mailer => mailer.PopulateBody(It.IsAny<MailMessage>(), "Welcome", null));            
        _userMailerMock.CallBase = true;

        //Act
        var mailMessage = _userMailerMock.Object.Welcome();
```

Fails on the following line in the Welcome() method (copied straight out of the wiki):

```
 PopulateBody(mailMessage, viewName: "Welcome");
```

The wiki is here: https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide

Similar (almost exactly the same) Question: [MvcMailer: Can't complete NUnit tests on Razor Views which use Url.Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575964/mvcmailer-cant-complete-nunit-tests-on-razor-views-which-use-url-action)

Anyone know how to fix/get around this? The linked question says I need to mock out the PopulateBody method which I have done (as per wiki).

Comment: This [issue was reported](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/issues/20) to the MVC Mailer team but was closed without a resolution.  Does anyone have a workaround/fix?

Comment: @Josh, unfortunately I still haven't found a fix or workaround. Guess this bug is in the hands of the MVC mailer devs...

Comment: a workaround is to change your code to this: `PopulateBody(mailMessage, "Welcome", null);` This will work because you have a mock setup for that overload of PopulateBody and not for the 2 parameter version of it..

Comment: @FilipCornelissen: finally a solution that worked! Thanks mate... :)

Comment: @FilipCornelissen dont you want to post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: done, now it can help the rest of the world ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a workaround is to change your code to this:

`PopulateBody(mailMessage, "Welcome", null);`

This will work because you have a mock setup for that overload of PopulateBody and not for the 2 parameter version of it..

Answer (score 3):

A quick addition to Filip's answer that somebody might find helpful: I am using version 4.0 of the MvcMailer package. I was using the `Populate(Action<MvcMailMessage> action)` method inside my mailer actions and noticed that it uses a ***four***-parameter version of `PopulateBody`:

```
// Mvc.Mailer.MailerBase (using ILSpy)
public virtual MvcMailMessage Populate(Action<MvcMailMessage> action)
{
    MvcMailMessage mvcMailMessage = new MvcMailMessage();
    action(mvcMailMessage);

    // Four parameters! (comment added by me)
    this.PopulateBody(mvcMailMessage, mvcMailMessage.ViewName, mvcMailMessage.MasterName, mvcMailMessage.LinkedResources);

    return mvcMailMessage;
}
```

As such, I found that setting up the mock with four parameters...

```
PopulateBody(mailMessage, "Welcome", "SomeMasterName", null);
```

...did the trick.

Comment: Thank you! The Wiki should be updated to the new version. Good work

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to mock HttpContext too. You can do this by creating a HttpContextBase mock object and assign it to your Controller object.

Comment: I'm just trying to test the mailer for now, not the controller that uses the mailer (if that makes any difference!).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is due to that you are reassigning a new mock to the `_userMailerMock` variable and therefore not actually mocking the `PopulateBody` method.

```
var _userMailerMock = new Mock<UserMailer>();
_userMailerMock.Setup(mailer => mailer.PopulateBody(It.IsAny<MailMessage>(), "Welcome", null));
_userMailerMock.CallBase = true;
```

Take out the second assignment `_userMailerMock = new Mock<UserMailer>();` the line before `Callbase = true;`

Comment: Oops I pasted the code into stackoverflow incorrectly. There is only 1 assigment to _userMailerMock in the code. Still get the same error.